# Either i am using Angular Renerer2 wrong, or it is broken. Can anyone figure this out?

Tags: angular, angular-renderer2

Using plain old javascript, this is so simple:

```
myElement.style.setProperty('property', 'value', 'important');
```

In Angular, not so much.
I have done an exhaustive search absolutely everywhere and can not find one single example for how to do this, so i am asking the question here.

**Either Renderer2 in Angular is broken or i am just doing this wrong.**

i import the following into my component:

```
import {ElementRef, Renderer2, RendererStyleFlags2 } from '@angular/core';
```

and, in my constructor:

```
constructor(private elRef: ElementRef,
            private renderer: Renderer2);
```

i set a style on an element in my template that works without issue:

```
this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.my-div'), 'color', '#fff');
```

when i try to set the important flag like this:

```
this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.my-div'), 'color', '#fff', RendererStyleFlags2.Important);
```

or like this:

```
this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.my-div'), 'color', '#fff', flags:RendererStyleFlags2.Important);
```

or like this:

```
public myFlags:RendererStyleFlags2;
this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.my-div'), 'color', '#fff', myFlags.Important);
```

or in another way like this:

```
public myFlags:RendererStyleFlags2.Important;
public myFlags:RendererStyleFlags2.Important = 1;
```

along with many other attempts using arrays and objects:

```
myFlags:any = {important: 1}
```

None of the above works.

This is the method as it exists in angular core:

```
setStyle(el: any, style: string, value: any, flags: RendererStyleFlags2): void {
    if (flags & RendererStyleFlags2.DashCase) {
      el.style.setProperty(
          style, value, !!(flags & RendererStyleFlags2.Important) ? 'important' : '');
    } else {
      el.style[style] = value;
    }
  }
```

**Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here?**

Comment: Did you try to set both flags? `RendererStyleFlags2.DashCase` and `RendererStyleFlags2.Important`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It feels like you either need to use both of the renderer flags or add `!important` to the string value instead.

```js
const flags = RendererStyleFlags2.DashCase | RendererStyleFlags2.Important;
this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.my-div'), 'color', '#fff', flags);
```

Or

```js
this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.my-div'), 'color', '#fff!important');
```

Comment: WOW, OK so your first suggestion, setting both flags works, but can you help me understand what setting the DashCase does exactly? I did not see any other change in the DOM outside of the inclusion of the !important flag.

Comment: Look at the code you posted from Angular core. It is checking for the `RendererStyleFlags2.DashCase` first to see which code path to go down.

Comment: My best guess is that if you want to change the `borderRadius` property in CSS, you can specify it as `borderRadius` or `border-radius`. The way you are setting the CSS in JS dictates which way you have to specify the property.

Comment: worst documentation, only shallow things are covered. If anything little bit complex we have to jump through API docs which don't have any clue on why a thing is there. You saved me after 2 hours of frustration. Thanks, Mr.Strimpel.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be to overwrite the `style` attribute with the `renderer`, for example like this:

```
this.renderer.setAttribute(myElementHere, 'style', 'color: #FFF !important');
```

But warning, it will remove / overwrite already existing inline styles. For this case you could read the value of the current `style` attribute and append / prepend it to the value, which will be overwritten.

Note that this solution is a bit, I would say, hacky, but if you can deal with it, you're good to go.

I did no performance tests or something like that (`setStyle` vs `setAttribute`).

This is just to complete the possibilities of overwriting inline styles.