# Angular : how to programatically set css style to body as important in typescript

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-template

Under my angular app

I'm using this code to set a  custom body style :

```
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
  }
```

for some specific scneario i myust add **"important"** to it

this would be like this :

```
   this.elementRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden !important';
```

But that is not working , and "important is not added to the style.

To note ; since i need to apply this for the body itself , and not to a specific html element unside my component ,  ngStyle cannot do it.

**Suggestions ??**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm unable to inject a style with an "!important" rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917608/im-unable-to-inject-a-style-with-an-important-rule)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) should work.

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.body.style.setProperty("overflow-y", "hidden", "important");
```

Comment: But WHY use Angular for that in the first place?? I just don't understand why `body { overflow-y : hidden !important }` in CSS wouldn't work? Why use Angular, with an elementRef, an ngOnInit and everything, simply to put a basic CSS rule on the body? It really seems to me that we are solving an extremely simple problem with a very complicated solution

Comment: @JeremyThille, obviously he is doing somthing wrong if you need to use js like that in angular. But we've all had such situations where it just needs a quick fix for something that might become too complicated otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

html:

```
<h2 #elem>hiper king</h2>
```

ts:

import { Component, ViewChild, Renderer2, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  title = 'stackApp';
  @ViewChild('elem') elem: ElementRef;
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elem.nativeElement, 'style', 'overflowY: hidden !important');
  }
}
```

Try this

Ref: [Either i am using Angular Renerer2 wrong, or it is broken. Can anyone figure this out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822754/either-i-am-using-angular-renerer2-wrong-or-it-is-broken-can-anyone-figure-thi)

Answer (score 1):

When you need to add a class to the `body`, Renderer2 is a good option. First create 2 classes:

```css
.overflowYHidden {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.overflowYHiddenImportant {
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

Now use the renderer:

```
import { Renderer2, RendererFactory2 } from '@angular/core';

// class declaration skipped

_renderer: Renderer2;

constructor(rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) {
  this._renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer('body', null);
}
```

I don't know what logic you're using for when to use important:

```
if (someCondition) {
  this._renderer.addClass(document.body, 'overflowYHidden');
  this._renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'overflowYHiddenImportant');
} else {
  this._renderer.addClass(document.body, 'overflowYHiddenImportant');
  this._renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'overflowYHidden');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Why use elementRefs? Just use [ngStyle]

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'overflowY' : 'hidden !important' }"></div>
```

or

```
<div [style.overflowY ]="'hidden !important'"></div>
```

Also, if it happens automatically on load (in `ngOnInit`), why not simply hardcode it in your template? And why don't you simply use CSS and add it with Angular?

Comment: i need to apply custom style to the body,  it s not  for a simple element u side my component

Comment: So why do you even use Angular at all? Why don't you apply CSS to the body directly? I'm lost, it seems to me that you want to do something extremely simple in a very complicated way

Comment: no ; i ve to activate / desactiavte a scroll on the  main page programmatically after c button click (which open a popup)

Comment: But still, why do you need Angular for that? A simple vanilla Javascript line would do. Select the body, add or remove a class, job done. This is still overly complicated.

Comment: cauz it's  basically an angular app ,

Comment: arghhhhhh OK so you just won't understand my point. Just keep using ElementRefs and ngOnInit when you can simply toggle a class with one line of pure JS IN YOUR ANGULAR COMPONENT, so it is still controlled by Angular if you need, but without all this complicated stuff. I would do this in one line in my Angular app, but you absolutely want to use plenty of complicated things and workarounds to reach the same result so... whatever floats your boat  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I give up

Comment: why you re angry , this is the point ; i want to adjust the body overflow when opening a popup and closin it ... if you may do it show me how